# Printing problem , Canon LBP2900

Tags: 12.04, printing, 32-bit, canon

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 , 32bit . when I'm printing nothing happen.

I actually install my printer drivers , canon LBP2900 from [canon site](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/Laser/i-SENSYS_LBP2900.aspx?type=download&page=1) , its contain 2 *.deb file :

1. cndrvcups-common_2.60-1_i386.deb
2. cndrvcups-capt_2.60-1_i386.deb

after installing them I done the following as suggested in forum:

1. Created the following directories:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /var/ccpd
   sudo mkfifo /var/ccpd/fifo0
   sudo mkdir /var/captmon
   ```
2. Registered the printer:

   ```
   sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP2900 -m CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp:/var/ccpd/fifo0 -E
   ```
3. Register the printer with ccpd daemon:

   ```
   sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP2900 -o /dev/usb/lp0
   ```
4. Start ccpd daemon:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start
   ```

all steps was successfully and even my printer added to printer list in system setting and if I want to print sth it is available but when I print sth after some minuets I get this from printer state :  " Idle - ccp send_data error, exit "

Of course the printer is connected , when I enter `lsusb` in terminal it is in the list.

and nothing will happen next just the jobs are in queue .

The posts that I used  : [printing Canon LBP2900 problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92698/printing-canon-lbp2900-problems)

http://www.unixmen.com/installation-canon-lbp2900-on-linux/

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Canon_LBP2900

Thanks,
Fari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the printer from the window System - Printers.

Uninstall cndrvcups-capt and cndrvcups-common with Ubuntu Sofware Center.

Go to this page:

http://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu/ ([archived copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20140220155009/https://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu/))

Find the link to download the script, unzip and run it.

The printer is not working.

The wrong way signal on the top of the screen tells us that something was wrong with the dependencies and that we have to type on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install -f cndrvcups-common
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f cndrvcups-capt
```

Dependencies are all right, but the printer is still silent.

Open the printer window and look at the properties: the URI is

```
ccp://localhost:59687.
```

Correct it in

```
ccp://localhost:59787.
```

The printer is still silent.

Type on the terminal

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd status
```

The answer is one number, not two: too bad.

Type on the terminal

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd restart
```

and then

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd status
```

The answer is two numbers. OK.

Try printing the test page, no paper on the printer, the printer stops and does not restart.

We have to start the printer monitor at bootstrap.

On the system setting - startup applications

click the Add button

Name: Canon printing status monitor

Command: `captstatusui -e -P LBP2900`

Description: Hidden until an error occurs

The printer now is working properly.

Comment: thanks you very much @Marcello , it really works after a generation! ^_^
but something wrong about the time when no paper on the printer , the printer stops and it will not work untill I restart the printer.

Comment: The link is dead